# Change label text from the button outside GridView asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

the code below only works on `GridViewCommandEventArgs` but this time i want to use this kind of method on a button click. how do i modify this code in order to use it for a button click. im looking into changing the text with a button that is outside the gridview.

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
Label label = row.FindControl("lbl_reviewDate") as Label;
label.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("d");
Label labelID = row.FindControl("lbl_id") as Label;
```

Comment: If your button is outside gridview then `e.CommandSource` won't work for you as you will be performing a button click event instead of **GridView RowCommand**. You would need to iterate in **GridView** to make desired changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
  protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in YourGridviewName.Rows)
        {

          Label label = row.FindControl("lbl_reviewDate") as Label;
          label.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("d");
          Label labelID = row.FindControl("lbl_id") as Label;
        }
    }
```